# Angular: How to get the total for a shopping website

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am absolutely a newbie to Angular and learning it by making a simple shopping webpage.
I created an input where you can input the item quantity for each product, and also it will show each item cost on the same `<div>`.
for example, a pen is $1, and I picked qty of 2, and it will show the total cost is $2 on the pen `<div>`; a pencil is $2, and I chose qty of 1, it will show $2 on the pencil `<div>`.
However, I am having a trouble with getting the subtotal of all the products together (like adding up the pen and pencil on the total div) in angular way.
So here is part of my html code(I only show it partially coz its too long):

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <header>
        <h1 class="text-left">Hello Auntie</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
            <h3>{{product.name}}
            <input placeholder="Enter Qty here..."  onfocus="this.type='number';" min="0"ng-model="product.quantity"/>
                <em class="pull-right">
                {{product.price | currency}}
                    <em class="pull-bottom"><p><font size="2">total cost: {{product.quantity * product.price | currency}}</font></p></em>
                </em>
            </h3>
```

and here is my code from my js file:

```
(function (){
var app = angular.module('helloAuntie', []);
app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = fashion;
});
var fashion =[{
    name: 'Dress',
    description: "100% cotton, free size, handmade item",
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
    price: 30.99,
    images:"image/dress.jpg",
    reviews: [{
        stars: 5,
        body: "The most beautiful dress ever!",
        author: "hotGirl@angular.com"
    },{
        stars: 3,
        body: "The dress is very pretty, but the size is smaller than I expected",
        author: "fatgirl@angular.com"
    }]
},{
    name: 'Rainbow Short',
    description: "Size: M/S, jeans quality",
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
    price: 20,
    images: "image/short.jpg",
    reviews: [{
        stars: 8,
        body: "Best outfit for coachella!",
        author: "hippies@angular.com"
    },{
        stars: 1,
        body: "after I washed it, the color was just fading, I am so disappointed",
        author: "disappointed@angular.com"
    },{
        stars: 3,
        body: "the quality is just ok, but hey 20$, what do you expect?",
        author: "feelOkcustomer@angular.com"
    }]
},{
    name: 'Shirt',
    description: "Size: M/S, free size",
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
    price: 15.50,
    images: "image/shirt.jpg",
    reviews: [{
        stars: 1,
        body: "Worst quality ever!",
        author: "socheap@angular.com"
    }]
}];
```

})();

Comment: push selected items to an array like `this.selectedItems=[]`. On changes to array update cart totals by looping over array. Then when user hits "checkout" you have cart items all ready to send to server from that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a function to call to recalculate the total price of the users cart every time they change the value. Try this

Add an ID to you input tag

```
<input id="some_input_id" placeholder="Enter Qty here..."  onfocus="this.type='number';" min="0"ng-model="product.quantity"/>
```

you'll need to keep track of your Inputs so you'll know when their values are changed. Next in your JS file add

```
app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = fashion;
    this.totals = 0;

    //This function calculates the user's total and stores it in this.totals
    this.updateTotals = function(){
       this.totals = 0;
       for each(var product in this.products){
           this.totals += (product.quantity * product.price);
       }
    }

    //Finally we add an event to be called every time one of the quantities on one of the products is changed
    jQuery('#some_input_id').on('input', function() {
        this.updateTotals();
    });

});
```

Now you can add {{totals}} somewhere in you controller area in your html file and it will update every time the user changes the quantity